# How do I tell if a 'г' sounds like a 'g' or a 'v'

Tags: произношение, алфавит

`г` normally sounds like a `g`, such as где. Sometimes though it can sound like a `v`, such as нового.

How do I tell which one is the correct one?

Comment: Also, see this question, [Why is the letter “г” in some of the Russian words pronounced differently as it should be?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/why-is-the-letter-г-in-some-of-the-russian-words-pronounced-differently-as-it/14454#14454)