# Why is the 'г' in "мягкий" pronounced like a 'х'?

Tags: произношение

According to these [consonant assimilation rules](http://webhome.auburn.edu/~mitrege/russian/tutorials/0029.html), the letters г and к form a voiced/voiceless pair, and the final consonant in the cluster voices or devoices the preceding consonant.

If these rules apply, then shouldn't the 'г' in "мягкий" be assimilated into another 'к'? Why is it pronounced like an 'х' instead (`mʲæxʲkʲɪj`)?

Comment: From the practical point I'd say, that in language learning "rules" are just generalizations, which should help one to remember things without memorizing 1m cases. But there are exceptions too. They certainly have explanations, but often it's easier to just remember an exception without finding an explanation. Like in English, the construct "it's part of a …". Why doesn't the word part have an article? Or 'just in case'? I've decided that for me it'd be harder to find an explanation, then simply remember the fact without one.

Comment: I wonder, what's the pronunciation of the Russian _волгкий_ (moist, damp, wet)? I've never heard the word pronounced, only saw it written. Is it also with [xʲ], kind of ['volxʲkʲij]?

Comment: @YellowSky  [волккий] first "к" is hard, second "к" is soft.

Comment: @YellowSky Даже можно образовать глагол. Волглив**а**ться = увлажн**я**ться. В противоположность, в**о**лгнуть = мокнуть.

Comment: @user907860 Definitely. I'm just trying to see if there is another "rule" that could help find out what the correct pronunciation is by just looking at a word. Kind of like how the 'г' in words like "Всего" and "сегодня" is pronounced like a /v/ because of reasons [explained here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14454/1729).

Comment: @user907860 This actually made me look into Portuguese phonology. As a native speaker, I had always assumed it had a fairly simple and predictable set of pronunciation rules. But revisiting it from the perspective of a new learner, it actually has quite a few special rules, exceptions, and exceptions to the exceptions. That's not even going into all the regional variations, of which there are many. I guess with any language you're just going to have to accept that not everything is going to be neatly defined.

Comment: @sanaris: Sorry, what is волккий?

Answer (score 3):

It is an exception to the general pronunciation of "г" ([g] / [k]). In native Russian words, a "г" directly before "к" or "ч" is pronounced [x].

Other exceptions of the pronunciation of "г":

- "г" is pronounced as в ( [v] / [ʋ] ) in genitive endings "-го" of adjectives, participles, their nominalizations (eg. "управля́ющего", "дежу́рного") and applicable pronouns (eg "его́", "како́го"); .
- "г" is pronounced [х] in "Бог"
- "г" is pronounced [ɦ] / [ɣ] in certain interjections ("ага", "гей") and  in the vocative "Го́споди".

Comment: [ɦ] / [ɣ] also in **ого**, [**э-ге-ге**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/э-ге-ге)

Answer (score 2):

In Belarussian (a close relative of Russian), the letter 'г' represents two different sounds; one forms a pair with 'х', and the other with 'к' (in the IPA, they're the velar fricative and the velar plosive, respectively). Russian, on the contrary, doesn't have the voiced velar fricative sound, but it has the unvoiced one — 'х'.

So you're half right — the pair is 'г'/'к'. It's just a different, non-existent 'г' in "мягкий" :D

Comment: Actually, Russian *does* have the voice velar fricative phoneme, it just doesn't have a distinct letter to represent it. It's an allophone of **x** and can be heard in: горох же [gʌˈroɣʒɨ] and бухгальтер [buˈɣal̡t̡ɪr], for instance.

Comment: @CocoPop are you conflating бухгалтер and бюстгальтер?

Comment: @mustaccio: No, that would be [b̡uzˈɣal̡t̡ɪr].

Comment: I'm talking about the spelling

Comment: @mustaccio: Oh, I didn't mean to add the m.z. — force of habit))

Answer (score 1):

Because it's actually not the pair **г/к**, but rather **г/к,х**.

Мягкий [м'aхк'ий].
Лёгкий [л'охк'ий].

Here ' stands for the soft sign/palatalization.

Also, despite any rules pursuant to which the (theoretical) pronunciation **рюкзак [р'угзак]** is prescribed, when you actually hear this word in speech, you can detect a little "aftersound", and, with some training, realize what letter is used because it actually contains a hint of the sound **[к']**.

There are even certain people who pronounce it in a way that kind of leans towards **[р'укзак]**. This **к** is closer to **киянка** than to **катер**.

Comment: That doesn't give any answer at all... In most Slavic languages the root is _M(a vowel)K_ (cf. Rus. _МЯКоть_). The question is the source of [x] and _why_ it alternates with [g] (cf. _мяГенький_), although the [Proto-Slavic form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/mękъkъ) was _*mękŭkŭ_.

Comment: @YellowSky Потому, что на определённом этапе звуковое разнообразие расширилось. Поэтому язык отошёл от стандартного "двузвучного" альтернирования.

Comment: "звуковое разнообразие расширилось" можно сказать только в масштабах эволюции, т.е. миллионов лет. В масштабах 1000-100 лет разнообразие только сужается, т.к. благодаря СМИ (тому же телевидению) люди говорят все более одинаково на огромных территориях. Например, в еще 2005-ом году на Украине куча народу говорила "на", а в 2008-ом году я заметил, что я сам непроизвольно стал говорить "в". Я так предполагаю, что после "помаранчевой революции" дали команду по телеканалам, чтоб они говорили только "в" и это дало эффект. Так что особенностей произношения т.п. становится меньше, в целом

Comment: Давайте разберёмся. Начнём с краткой формы. Протослав. _*mękŭkŭ_ должно было бы закономерно дать рус. _*мякок_, а дало _мягок_, со звонким Г. Допустим, К между гласными озвончилось в Г (хотя ни в одном другом слав. языке такого не произошло). Но тогда почему в _мякоть_ тоже между гласными К остался? Откуда взялся этот Г?

Comment: @user907860 И до сих пор огромные массы носителей говорят "на Украине", не считая это чем-то "плохим". По правилам "на Камчатке", но почему-то "в Британии", но опять же, "на Мальдивах". Но при этом "в Японии", "на Бермудах". "В Америке", но при этом "на Аляске". Такова особенность языка. "В Германии", но "на нимеччине" - вот это вообще корка.

Comment: @YellowSky "Мягкий". Там же всё равно просвечивает "г-к". Я не могу подобрать правильной аналогии, но вот в слове "рюкзак" явно есть носители, которые не склоняются к "г(х)", а высвечивают "к". "Рюк-зак". Так и говорят.

Comment: Я это просто привел как пример, как СМИ влияют на то, как люди что-то произносят. Т.е. 1000 лет назад, когда никаких СМИ не было, в селе за 30 километров от тебя уже могли говорить по-другому. А за 1000км уже слабо вообще можно было понять язык. Сегодня же все больше и больше людей на огромных расстояних говорят все более одинаково. Т.е. разнообразие произношений в целом сужается, **а по вашей версии оно со славянских времен расширилось**

Comment: Пример про рюкзак тут совершенно не в тему, не вижу вообще никакой связи. А вот _волгкий_ — это да, тут всё как и должно быть, регресивная ассимиляция по звонкости-глухости ГК > КК. Вот это и есть вопрос: почему не говорится _*мяККий_? Вот на белорусском так и есть: _мяккі_.

Comment: I see. How common is the г--х assimilation (as opposed to г--к)? I don't normally find this former pair listed.

Comment: @user907860 вы абсолютно не правы, 1000 лет - это огромный срок, за который фонетический строй может претерпевать очень сильные изменения - далеко не всегда это будет уменьшение количества фонем.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this phenomenon is called *linguistic economy principle* in English, or *закон лингвистической экономии* in Russian. It refers to when you have to pronounce certain words a special way just because it's easier to pronounce them that way. I think you'll agree with me when I say that to pronounce *мягкий* with [x] is much easier and sounds better than with [к].